# why do we treat independent and dependent variables in a differential equations differently?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

let $g'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2};x \neq 0$-------(1)

since, $\int g'(x)dx= \left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{1}{x}+c_1;x>0\\ \mathbf{and} \\ \frac{1}{x}+c_2;x<0\end{array}\right.$-----(1.1)
because, g'(x) is a piece-wise function and the pieces of the integral of g'(x) can differ by a constant and still have the same derivative.

then why do we have,

$\int dy=\int ydx$

$\int \frac{dy}{y}=\int dx$-------(2)

$=>\left\{\begin{array}{ll}ln|y|=x+c_1;y>0\\ \mathbf{or}  \\ln|y|=x+c_2;y<0\end{array}\right.$

$=>\left\{\begin{array}{ll}y=c_1e^x;y>0\\ \mathbf{or}  \\y =c_2e^x;y<0\end{array}\right.$-------(3)

i know, that having **or**  in (3) makes sense (because if we had **and** instead then, the resulting curve would *not* be a function and thus derivatives would *not* be defined at all.)
but if we follow the same method we used for integrating (1), to integrate (2), then we should have **and** in (3) instead of **or**.

so, for what reason do we end up with **and** in (1.1) but **or** in (3)?

to make clear my point , let's consider
$\int \frac{dy}{y}=\int \frac{dx}{x}$-----(4)

$=>\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \left\{\begin{array}{ll}ln|y|=ln|x|+c_1;y>0,x>0\\ \mathbf{or}  \\  ln|y|=ln|x|+c_2;y<0,x>0  \end{array}\right. \\ \mathbf{and} \\  \left\{\begin{array}{ll}ln|y|=ln|x|+c_3;y>0,x<0\\ \mathbf{or}  \\ln|y|=ln|x|+c_4;y<0,x<0\end{array}\right. \end{array}\right.$

see! , when it is the independent variable we use **and**(we say it's the same function) , but when its the dependent variable we use **or**( we say there are actually two different solutions, one of which will be eliminated by the initial condition). why do we do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you encounter a problem in your equation, the typical fix is to find a solution for a specific portion without the problem. When you do that for two different portions of the dependent variable, you wind up with two different solutions that suggest different outputs for the same input, so they can’t both be the answer. When you do that to the input, then you’re defining solutions for two different sections so the different solutions can both be part of the same function.